# Need Help . I need to determine the values in the "Final Status" column in a SharePoint list based on certain conditions involving other columns

Tags: list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I need to determine the values in the "Final Status" column in a SharePoint list based on certain conditions involving other columns.

Here are the rules:

- If all columns (Billing Status, Cash App Status, Order release Status, Final Status - Cash App) are empty, then "Final Status" should be set to "Hold - Pending w Biller".
- If Billing Status is "Invoice sent to customer" and other columns are blank, "Final Status" should be "Hold - Waiting for Payment".
- If Billing Status is "Invoice sent to customer" and Cash App Status is "Payment Found" while other two columns are blank, "Final Status" should be "Hold - Pending w Order Releaser".
- If Billing Status is "Invoice sent to customer", Cash App Status is "Payment Found", and Order release Status is "Order Released" while Final Status - Cash App is blank, then "Final Status" should be "Pending w CashApp".
- If Billing Status is "Invoice sent to customer", Cash App Status is "Payment Found", Order release Status is "Order Released", and Final Status - Cash App is "Payment Applied/Workflow Closed", then "Final Status" should be "Completed".
- If Billing Status is "Invoice sent to customer", Cash App Status is "Payment Found", Order release Status is "Order Released", and Final Status - Cash App is "Payment amount doesn't match", then "Final Status" should be "Released - Pending w Estimator".
- If Billing Status is "Invoice sent to customer", Cash App Status is "Payment Found", Order release Status is "Order Released", and Final Status - Cash App is "No open orders/Invoices to apply", then "Final Status" should be "Released - Pending w Estimator".
- If Billing Status is "Invoice sent to customer", Cash App Status is "Payment Found", Order release Status is "Order Released", and Final Status - Cash App is "Not applied RC11 - Sales order not shipped", then "Final Status" should be "Released - Pending w CashApp".
- If Billing Status is "Invoice sent to customer" and Cash App Status is "Payment Found & SO # missing" while Order release Status is blank, "Final Status" should be "Hold - Pending w Estimator".
- If Billing Status is "Invoice sent to customer" and Cash App Status is "Payment Not Found" while other two columns are blank, then "Final Status" should be "Hold - Waiting for Payment".
- If Billing Status is "Additional information requested from Estimator" and other columns are blank, then "Final Status" should be "Hold - Pending w Estimator".
- If Billing Status is "Additional information requested from Estimator", Cash App Status is "Payment Found & SO # missing", and other two columns are blank, then "Final Status" should be "Hold - Pending w Estimator".
- If Billing Status is "Additional information requested from Estimator", Cash App Status is "Payment Not Found", and other two columns are blank, then "Final Status" should be "Hold - Waiting for Payment".

Here is what I tried so far:

```
    =IF(
        ISBLANK([Billing Status]), 
        "Hold - Pending w Biller",
        IF(
            [Billing Status]="Invoice sent to customer", 
            IF(
                ISBLANK([Cash App Status]), 
                "Hold - Waiting for Payment",
                IF(
                    [Cash App Status]="Payment Found", 
                    IF(
                        ISBLANK([Order release Status]), 
                        "Hold - Pending w Order Releaser",
                        IF(
                            [Order release Status]="Order Released", 
                            IF(
                                [Final Status - Cash App]="Payment Applied/Workflow Closed", 
                                "Completed",
                                IF(
                                    [Final Status - Cash App]="Payment amount doesn't match" OR [Final Status - Cash App]="No open orders/Invoices to apply", 
                                    "Released - Pending w Estimator",
                                    IF(
                                        [Final Status - Cash App]="Not applied RC11 - Sales order not shipped", 
                                        "Released - Pending w CashApp",
                                        "incomplete order"
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            "Pending w CashApp"
                        )
                    ),
                    "Hold- Pending w Estimator"
                )
            ),
            "incomplete order"
        )
    )
```

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? SharePoint Online or SharePoint On-premises (which version exactly)?

Comment: I guess Sharepoint online